# Magento 2 : How to remove _required class for region and region_id in shipping address?

Tags: shipping, form-validation, magento2.3.3, checkout-page

I have updated Magento 2.3.3 after that I'm getting the error in `region` and `region_id` on the checkout page. So I need to remove the `_required` class in the checkout shipping form.

Please refer attached file for reference.

[image]

Comment: which error ???

Comment: http://prntscr.com/qis6gt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the **region** field optional from admin, follow below steps.

**Step 1**

- Login to the back end of Magento 2.
- On the Admin sidebar, navigate to **Stores > Settings > Configuration**.
- Under the panel of **General**, select **General**.
- Scroll down to explore the **State Option** section.

**Step 2**

In the **State Option** list:

- Choose the country where the **State/ Region** is **required**.
- In the box of **Allow to Choose State if it is Optional for Country**,
  select **Yes** if the state field is not **compulsory** including the
  optional State field, select **No** if the state field is not **compulsory**
  but omitting the State field.

Click **Save Config**. to save all the process and **flush cache** and check.

Comment: Thank you . It's working for me.

Comment: @Priya, Happy Coding..!